# std::unique_ptr as out argument to a function

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

```
struct cls{
    ~cls(){std::cout<<"dtor\n";}
};

void foo(cls** pp){
    *pp = new cls;
}

int main()
{
    cls* raw_ptr = 0;    
    foo(&raw_ptr);
    std::unique_ptr<cls> u_ptr{raw_ptr};
}
```

Is there any way to directly access the `raw_pointer` in the `unique_ptr` to pass to the function `foo(cls** pp)`?

Or

```
cls* raw_ptr = 0;    
foo(&raw_ptr);
std::unique_ptr<cls> u_ptr{raw_ptr};
```

Is it the only way?

Note: I cannot change the signature of the function `foo`.

Comment: [`unique_ptr::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get *read-only* access to the pointer inside a `unique_ptr` by using [`unique_ptr::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get). This returns a copy of the pointer stored.

However, I understand your question as to whether there is a way to mutate the pointer in the `unique_ptr` *in situ;* here, the answer is **no**. You have to do the raw-to-unique dance you mention.

Of course, even if you can't change the signature of `foo`, you can certainly provide your own function to wrap that dance. It could even be an overload of `foo`:

```
std::unique_ptr<cls> foo()
{
  cls *p = nullptr;
  foo(&p);
  return std::unique_ptr<cls>{p};
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67e401876546d5dd)

Answer (score -1):

unique_ptr<>::get() - it returns a pointer to the owned object, without releasing ownership of the object.